# How to set query timeout on PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there a way to get Connection.prepareStatement() to throw an error or return, instead of waiting for a row lock?

I am trying to implement cross-process synchronization with using a prepared statement, that i do not commit, so it grabs a write lock on a specific row.  In the other processes it tries to prepare the sql statement, then it hangs while the original process finishes up.  I need this to let me know it is hanging, so i can stop the function, and try again whenever it gets rescheduled.

Any ideas? Ive been googling for days, and can't seem to find a yes/no to this.

Comment: Might be database specific - what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Will do once the 8 hours are up.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Im a fool, I figured this out yesterday and just forgot...

To solve it, do

```
preparedstatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
preparedstatement.setQueryTimeout(seconds);
```

and then just catch the exception.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about `@since Java 7,` and neither did anyone else.

Comment: I wasn't able to find proof either, but I didn't look all that hard.  I have removed it.